# section uitable by current date?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, date

i want the user to input a row into the table...and the row to automatically make a table section for the day it was added and keep it in order by day..

aka the user added a row to the table today...put it under feb 22...tomorrow they will add another cell put it under create another section  feb 23, and add the row to it

Answer (score 0):

```
this will help...

today = [NSDate date];
dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy :EEEE"];
dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
NSLog(@"date: %@", dateString);
[dateFormat release];
gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
components = [gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:today];
```

[components setDay:([components day]-([components weekday]-2))];

```
NSDate *lastDayofweek = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components1];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat_last = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat_last setDateFormat:@"MMMM d,yyyy"];
NSString *dateString_last = [dateFormat_last stringFromDate:lastDayofweek];
[dateFormat_last autorelease];
NSDate *beginningOfWeek = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat_first = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat_first setDateFormat:@"MMMM d,yyyy"];
NSString *dateString_first = [dateFormat_first stringFromDate:beginningOfWeek];
[dateFormat_first autorelease];
```